# Implementing OpenID in ASP5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm attempting to implement Steam OpenID integration into an ASP5/MVC6 site. The existing OpenID libraries do not work with ASP5 as they seem to rely on HttpContext, which doesn't exist.

This is the only compatible library that I can find:

```
 "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-beta4",
```

I've configured it in Startup.ConfigureServices like so:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ..
        services.ConfigureOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://steamcommunity.com/openid";
            options.ClientId = "[ClientIDHere]";
        });
    }
```

and in Startup.Configure:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication();
```

My real question is a simple one, how do I actually *use* this library in my application to create the OpenID requests? Documentation seems non-existent on this library (typical for a beta, of course) and examples are scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: the Steam authentication provider for ASP.NET 5 is now online. You can visit https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers for more information.**

---

Sadly, Steam relies on OpenID 2.0, which is not (and won't be) supported by ASP.NET 5. Natively, only OAuth2 and OpenID Connect (**based on OAuth2 and not on OpenID 2.0**) are supported by the default authentication middleware shipped with ASP.NET 5.

I guess you were previously using the Steam provider for OWIN/Katana that was developed by the community: https://github.com/RockstarLabs/OwinOAuthProviders/tree/master/Owin.Security.Providers/Steam
Most of these providers - based on OAuth2 - will be ported as part of the `aspnet-contrib` project: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers.

Porting the OpenID 2.0 providers is not in the immediate plans, but you can open a new thread on https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers/issues and vote for the Stream provider.

Comment: FYI, the Steam provider will be merged soon: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers/issues/1

Comment: Reply to your update, using `https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers`. I added `app.UseSteamAuthentication()` to `Configure()`, but there is no such Extension. I Installed `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server + Extension`. What am I missing? I also added `using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Extensions;`

Comment: The OpenID 2.0 Steam provider has its own package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Steam/ (note that it has nothing to do with the OpenID Connect server middleware nor with OpenID Connect in general)

Comment: Thank you, totally missed it! :) Now I just need to figure out if the EF7 migrations handle the auth tables in my DB Edit: Okay, yes, looks that way... CreateIdentitySchema...nice